# UITableViewCell only sized correctly when textLabel wraps

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am using the standard UITableViewCell via Xamarin.iOS and the style I am using is UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle

I have defined my UITableView to have

```
RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension
EstimatedRowHeight = 44.0f
```

I need both of the Labels to be Wrappable and I can do this by saying

```
cell.TextLabel.Lines = 0;
cell.TextLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
cell.DetailTextLabel.Lines = 0;
cell.DetailTextLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
```

The problem I am having is that the Height of cell is **only** changing when textLabel needs to wrap. If the longer text is in the detailText a height change does not get triggered.

I am assuming this is a bug but it seems such an obvious use-case I must be doing something wrong. I have attached to screenshots in case the scenario needs further explanation

**Here the long wrappable text is in the TextLabel**
[image: The main label, textLabel has the long text]

**Here the long wrappable text is in the DetailTextLabel**
[image: The subtitle label, detailTextLabel has the long text]

Comment: you have to adjust the height of the cell when the text needs to wrap

Comment: I am using AutoLayout and AutomaticDimension on the Table Definition so it should "just work". Also that would not explain why it adjusts height when wrapping top label but not bottom label

Comment: Autolayout will resize your objects within the cell. As for why your it wraps like that, maybe you have a bottom constraint on the `DetailTextLabel`. Do you have a sample project i can look at?

Comment: Sorry I was away over xmas. I am trying the default cell so I have no constraints of my own applied.